# Single mongoDB database with separate folders

Tags: mongodb, directory

I need separate more than 2 databases  located different folders but it should be running same port number and same instance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [directoryPerDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) in the configuration for separating the DBs into different folders in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another folder(ex: mongodb2) dbpath for the second instance, and run it in different port(ex: 27010)

```
 mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb2 --port 27010
```

But the best way of doing this would be creating dedicated mongod configuration files like `mongod-DV.conf` and `mongod-STAGE.conf`. In these files you can specify dbpath, logpath folders, bind_ip, port and pidfilepath specific to each mongod instance so that your instances will not affect each other